# Image Uploads Not Working Correctly with PHP 7.2 +

Tags: php, forms

I'm creating a HTML / PHP form with a file upload field. I've been building it with PHP 7.1 and everything was working as expected, but when I tried running a newer version of PHP some image files don't seem to upload properly. Of the types I've tested HEIC and PNG don't seem to process correctly in PHP 7.2 or above.

Code:

```php
function get_mime_type($file) {
    $mtype = false;
    if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } elseif (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
        $mtype = mime_content_type($file);
    } 
    return $mtype;
}

    //Attachment Checks
    if (!empty($_FILES['attachment'])) { //If there are attachments
        $count = count($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
        if ($count > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {

                //File Format Check
                $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                $imageMIME = get_mime_type($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
                if (!in_array($imageFileType, $validExtensions)){
                    $fileFormatError = 1;
                }
                if (!in_array($imageMIME, $validMIMETypes)){
                    $fileFormatError = 1;
                }
                echo $imageMIME . " ";
            }
        }

        //Checks
        if (array_sum($_FILES["attachment"]["size"]) > ($totalFileSizeLimit * 1048576)){
            $fileSizeError = 1;
        }
    }
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES['attachment']); echo '</pre>';
```

Output with PHP 7.1:

```
application/octet-stream image/png image/jpeg application/pdf
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMG_1209.HEIC
            [1] => vlcsnap-2018-09-14-09h25m12s582.png
            [2] => IMG_0919.JPG
            [3] => Notifications Report.pdf
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/octet-stream
            [1] => image/png
            [2] => image/jpeg
            [3] => application/pdf
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/phpELiNGi
            [1] => /tmp/phpUQzMvA
            [2] => /tmp/phpTsoccW
            [3] => /tmp/php4u2G9k
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2896766
            [1] => 2681160
            [2] => 2066662
            [3] => 79876
        )

)
```

Output with PHP 7.2 or above:

```
image/jpeg application/pdf
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMG_1209.HEIC
            [1] => vlcsnap-2018-09-14-09h25m12s582.png
            [2] => IMG_0919.JPG
            [3] => Notifications Report.pdf
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => image/jpeg
            [3] => application/pdf
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => /tmp/phpHO95fL
            [3] => /tmp/phpeGaIre
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 2066662
            [3] => 79876
        )

)
```

Comment: Are you using the same `magic.mime` file? See: [mime_content_type()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type)

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't changed anything about the magic.mine file for PHP 7.1 or any other version so not sure how I'd check

Comment: did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: I have the same on PHP 7.4 ! Did you solve your issue ?